# CheckBoxFor - want to return false when checked, true when unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I am using CheckBoxFor, and right now when the checkbox is checked it is returning True, and vice versa. However, I want to do the opposite, aka:
Checked -> return false and Unchecked -> return true

Is this possible?

```
<label id="var1" class="btn btn-ip-select ">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.var1)
   Variable 1
</label>
<label id="var2" class="btn btn-ip-select">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.var2)
   Variable 2
</label>
```

Comment: If it was me, I wouldn't tamper with built in controls, why not just negating the value on the server side? You can write a custom model binder to negate the check box value, so in your action method, you would always get the desired value.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini that is what I am doing now. The problem is that I am using a toggle button. So when I reload the page the button is the opposite of what it should be because it's pulling its value from the DB. (Aka when it's checked, it returns false, then page reloads and it goes to unchecked since that's the value in the DB.) I was hoping there was a way to simply change the default values of the checkbox, but it doesn't sound like there is.